# Component is not rendered after upgraded from reactor-router v3 to v4

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

This is my v3 `react-router` code. It is a nested route.

```
 <Route
     path="/"
     components={App}
  >

    <Route
     path="/path/a"
     components={ContainerA}
    />
    <Route
     path="/path/b"
     components={ContainerB}
    />
  </Route>
```

After I upgraded to v4, nothing is rendered anymore. Why?

```
<Switch>
   <Route
     exact
     path="/"
     components={App}
   />
    <Route
     path="/path/a"
     components={ContainerA}
    />
    <Route
     path="/path/b"
     components={ContainerB}
    />
  </Route>
 </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `components` is not used anymore. need to change to `component`